# preupg: error: No such file or directory: '/usr/share/preupgrade/README'

Tags: redhat, centos6, centos7

```
yum -y install redhat-upgrade-tool preupgrade-assistant-contents

preupg --force
```

Output:

```
preupg: error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/preupgrade/README'
The command 'preupg --force' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Needs "sudo" in front?

Comment: This is in a Dockerfile.
I don't think I need sudo for this .

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the error with Docker image for Cloudera Express which is based on Centos 6.10. What I did was to manually create README and README.kickstart (yeah, it fails on both) taken from:
https://github.com/upgrades-migrations/preupgrade-assistant/tree/master/doc

After this particular issue is fixed, the tool fails on:

```
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/openscap/xsl/security-guide.xsl"
compilation error: file /usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 40 element import
xsl:import : unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/security-guide.xsl
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/openscap/xsl/oval-report.xsl"
compilation error: file /usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 41 element import
xsl:import : unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/oval-report.xsl
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/openscap/xsl/sce-report.xsl"
compilation error: file /usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 42 element import
xsl:import : unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/sce-report.xsl
OpenSCAP Error:: Could not parse XSLT file '/usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl' [oscapxml.c:416]
Unable to open file /root/preupgrade/result.html
Usage: preupg [options]

preupg: error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/preupgrade/result.html'
```

To overcome this one, we must erase the existing version of openscap (I had openscap 1.2) and install openscap-1.0.8-1.0.1 from http://dev.centos.org/centos/6/upg and redo the upgrade.

```
yum erase openscap
yum install http://dev.centos.org/centos/6/upg/x86_64/Packages/openscap-1.0.8-1.0.1.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm
yum install redhat-upgrade-tool preupgrade-assistant-contents
```